# Dynamodb error : Either the keyconditions or keyconditionexpression parameter must be specified in the request

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-toolkit

I am observing an unexpected outcome when querying a DynamoDB table using the AWS DynamodB Document Model in C#.

My table `users` has a username primary key. The GSI was set in for `user_type`, `user_id` and `username` keys.

[image: Querying my dynamodb]

This table works when I insert a document, but when querying a non-indexed but GSI-ed column, it returns this error:

> Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.

I have specified the condition in a filter object. Why am I asked to provide `KeyConditions` or `KeyConditionExpression`? Is it mandatory to specify them? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Its not 100% clear from the documentation but I believe if you are using the DocumentModel library [Query will only work if your GSI has a range key as well as partition key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryMidLevelDotNet.html). Instead I would consider using the standard sdk [QueryRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetQuerying.html)

Another thing to check is that you are using [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_DocumentModel.htm), because in [version 1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_DynamoDB_DocumentModel.htm) you have to specify the haskey explicitly